# как определить на какой элемент нажали?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Я сделал адаптер с 2 карточками и 3 textview и вывожу это в RecycleView
при нажатии на какой-то элемент, например на карточку, мне нужно понимать какой текст в этой карточке. 
не вешать же обработчик на каждый элемент, при чем так можно сделать только на текст. 
Как решить проблему?

Comment: да вешать обработчик, почему это кажется вам не подходящим? и обработчик нажатия можно повесить на любой view, почему вы считаете, что только на текст?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас есть два варианта.

1. В этом варианте вы можете создать обработчик событий в функции `onBindViewHolder`:

`holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new ...)`

и дальше вы можете в логи или как-то по-другому выводить данные по кликнутому элементу.

2. Второй вариант более интересный:
   в адаптере вы должны создать слушатель на нажатия

   `private final OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new MyOnClickListener();
   @Override
   public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
       View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.myview, parent, false);
       view.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
       return new MyViewHolder(view);
   }`

и дальше сам метод `onClick`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(final View view) {
    int itemPosition = mRecyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(view);
    String item = mList.get(itemPosition);
    Toast.makeText(mContext, item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

вот [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick) на первоисточник для второго варианта. Лично я пользуюсь первым вариантом, но еще я так же использую длительное нажатие на элемент для доп. действий.

Надеюсь один из вариантов будет решением вашей проблемы. Удачи :)

Comment: первый вариант помог, но как мне узнать, что при клике на карточку я попал в определенную тему?
например есть карта и на ней текст "глава 1"
точное определение я смогу сделать при нажатии на текст, но если я нажал на карту, то не знаю как

Comment: вы можете в логи вывести, например, значение того что находится на карточке. Либо есть еще вариант - сделать слушатель нажатия на элемент карточки. То есть например у вас там есть текстовое поле и картинка, вы можете сделать слушатель отдельно на картинку а отдельно на поле. И дальше уже вы сможете например в логи вывести значение на которое попали

Comment: сделал через костыль.. getDescription() :) 
Если есть более нормальный вариант, можете сказать, а так спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.